# How to control Brightness on Acer Laptop

Tags: brightness

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 in an Acer Timeline X 5830TG and brightness controls were not working (Fn + Key), even the Ubuntu's one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution:

Edit GRUB:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

then:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot.

Controls are working.

Comment: Works on #! Crunchbang Waldorf too on a native install to Aspire S5

Comment: YEEES! thank you! so many brightness ubuntu issues, so many posts... finally I found the one for me! after monnnths!

Comment: Didn't work for me sadly on Linux Mint 19.1 with an Acer Aspire 5810TG.

Answer (score 0):

Most simple and fast way to do this....
Use this command

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

Set the value in between 0 to 1 like in this case it is 0.5
This works for me 
Try this !!!

Comment: But this is for manual bright up with console? My answer is to enable the buttons of the keyboard